# How to display a button in header on only one specific page in mobile view

Tags: html, css

I have a button in my theme header so displayed the button in header. Then the issue was to display this button on only one specific page in header section other pages should not show this button so I did this with the help of below code:

```
 <style>
 .header-menu-btn {display: none !important}
.page-id-1675 .header-menu-btn {display: inline !important}
</style>
```

Now the issue is that its not displaying in mobile view mean when we open website in mobile the button do not displays so how can I display it on mobile as well as on pc on a specific page:
Here is the code which I tried but nothing happen:

```
 <style>
    @media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
.page-id-1675 .header-menu-btn {
        display: inline!important;
    }
```

}

Comment: Did you use the dev tools of a browser to switch to mobile view and inspect the button? Maybe thanks to the theme you're using the parent element doesn't appear on mobile or something.

Comment: 1. Drop these `!important` evils. 2. Have you inspected page to see why it's not shown?

Comment: I use !important but it do not works actually this button is in the nav menu bar when the nav menu shifts into the toggle button this button also disappears but I changed the media quries from the theme files and then tried to but still this button do not appears

Comment: Here is the link for that page   https://umacollege.geekss.com.au/register

Comment: Please do not use irrelevant tags - how is this question related to Javascript or PHP?

Comment: @NicoHaase tags removed thanks for correcting

Answer (score 0):

```css
header img{width:100px; display:none;}

@media(max-width:500px){
  header img{display:block;}
}
```

```html
<header>
 <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550587542-1668407b73d2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80">
</header>
```

use this media query for mobile devices..

```
<style>
    @media(max-width:500px){
      /** input this css **/
    }
   </style>
```

Comment: no its not working

Comment: use this style tag first like eg:
<style>
  header img{display:none ;}
@media(max-width:500px){
      header img{display:block !important;}
    }
</style>